# Change Spaces to Commas until All Changed

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have some code that is changing spaces to commas through `replace(' ',',')`, but it only changes the first space. How can you do this so that it changes every one. Maybe with a `for` statement?

**ALSO**

Is there a way to check if there is already a comma before the spaces that are changed so that there is never multiple commas in the page? Maybe after updating test if there are two or more commas next to eachother?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: use a regex as the first argument ... `/\s+/g` - note: no quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression and the global flag.

```js
console.log("    ".replace(/\s+/g,','))
```

Comment: thanks works great! I didn't know of the global flag thing!

Comment: You could enhance the regex expression for the case of looking for spaces followed by commas. Regex has many great features but can take a while to get it to work for all scenarios. I recommend hiding an online regex engine while with these if you require more advanced cases.